# How to add Post view counts using cookies in PHP Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, codeigniter-3

I am trying to add Post view counts using cookies in PHP Codeigniter. I have created a custom library(snippetfunctions) in which I have created a function(add_count) as shown below

```
  public function add_count($table,$column,$value)
{

$CI =& get_instance();//CI super object
$check_visitor = $CI->input->cookie(urldecode($value), FALSE);

 $ip = $CI->input->ip_address();
// if the visitor visit this article for first time then //
//set new cookie and update article_views column  ..
//you might be notice we used slug for cookie name and ip 
//address for value to distinguish between articles  views
if ($check_visitor == false) {
    $cookie = array(
        "name"   => urldecode($value),
        "value"  => "$ip",
        "expire" =>  time() + 0,
        "secure" => false
    );

    $CI->input->set_cookie($cookie);
$CI->Constant_model->update_counter($table,$column,urldecode($value));
}
}
```

and I used this function in my Controller file to add the count

```
$this->snippetfunctions->add_count('snippets','counter_views',$slug);
```

Where `snippets` is the table name, `counter_views` is the column name and `$slug`  is the URL of the post which is used to identify the post.

The error I am getting is shown in image

[image]

Model function

```
 function update_counter($table, $column, $value)
{
    // return current article views 
    $this->db->where($column, urldecode($value));
    $this->db->select('counter_views');
    $count = $this->db->get($table)->row();
    // then increase by one 
    $this->db->where($column, urldecode($value));


    $this->db->set('counter_views', ($count['counter_views'] + 1));
    $this->db->update($table);
}
```

Comment: what did you try to solve the  `3 parameter` issue?

Comment: can you share your model code too?

Comment: Edited, please check @M.Hemant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, hope this helps you
`3600` seconds and it means Current Time + 1 hour, your cookie will expire in one hour

```
$cookie = array(
        "name"   => urldecode($value),
        "value"  => "$ip",
        "expire" =>  3600,//changes seconds for 1 hour from current time
        "secure" => false
    );
```

Model:

```
function update_counter($table, $column, $value)
{
    // return current article views 
    $this->db->where($column, urldecode($value));
    $this->db->select('counter_views');
    $count = $this->db->get($table)->row('counter_views');

    $this->db->reset_query();
    // then increase by one 
    $this->db->set('counter_views', ($count + 1));//changes
    $this->db->where($column, urldecode($value));
    $this->db->update($table);
}
```

Comment: Getting this error Severity: Warning

Message: setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be integer, float given

Comment: Should i use Id instead of url slug?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/Constant_model.php

Line Number: 288

Comment: Can you tell me this 288 line number? Code updated again

Comment: Line number 288 - $this->db->set('counter_views', ($count->counter_views + 1));//changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192135/discussion-between-m-hemant-and-upasana-chauhan).

Comment: Error gone!! but counter view not increasing

Answer (score -1):

Please check this code:

```
public function add_count($table,$column,$value)
{

$CI =& get_instance();//CI super object
$check_visitor = $CI->input->cookie(urldecode($value), FALSE);

 $ip = $CI->input->ip_address();
// if the visitor visit this article for first time then //
//set new cookie and update article_views column  ..
//you might be notice we used slug for cookie name and ip 
//address for value to distinguish between articles  views
if ($check_visitor == false) {
    $cookie = array(
        "name"   => urldecode($value),
        "value"  => "$ip",
        "expire" =>  30,
        "secure" => false
    );

    $CI->input->set_cookie($cookie);
$CI->Constant_model->update_counter($table,$column,urldecode($value));
}
}
```

Comment: what is the difference here? only `30`? can you tell me why `30`? and why not `time()+0`?

Comment: 30 means 30 seconds. time()+0 means your cookie will save for current time + 0 second

Comment: getting this error Now - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yizb6f7e46bwih/Screenshot%202019-04-20%2010.54.55.png?dl=0

Comment: can you please share whole code so I can get exact issue